# How do I prevent firebase accessToken from expiring after 1 hour?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am building an App using firebase authentication. I pass in the firebase token to the API auth headers to validate the API.

The issue is after 1 hour the token expires and the API does not work anymore? How can I refresh the auth token every time it expires so that essentially the token never expires when the user is logged in.

I am using a auth context

here is AuthContext.jsx

```
  function getRefreshToken() {
    auth.onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      await user?.getIdToken().then(async (token) => token);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // setInterval(() => {
    // auth.onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
    //   await user?.getIdToken(true).then((token) => {
    //     setCurrentUser({
    //       ...currentUser,
    //       user: user || null,
    //       isVerified: user ? user.emailVerified : false,
    //       email: user ? user.email : '',
    //       accessToken: user ? token : '',
    //     });
    //     console.log(token, 'token');
    //   });
    // });

    // logout();
    // }, 3300000); // every 55 minutes set the access token to the new idToken

    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser({
        ...currentUser,
        user: user || null,
        isVerified: user ? user.emailVerified : false,
        email: user ? user.email : '',
        accessToken: user ? user.Aa : '',
      });
      setLoading(false);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Comment: i never used firebase but may this article help you ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Comment: How you tried this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#idtokenforcingrefresh_:?

Comment: Having a non-expiring token would be a pretty big security risk. But you're already listening for `onIdTokenChanged`, which should be enough to get the updated token whenever the SDK automatically refreshes it. What problem do you have when you run the code you shared?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually refresh the token when it expires.

Store the token's expiry time somewhere. When you make an API call (assuming you're using axios), you can use a request interceptor to add the token. Just check if its expired first - if it is, fetch a new one using the refresh token and then make the API call. If it is not, just send the request.